# Are distance functions necessarily nonsmooth on the cut locus?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and fix $p\in M$. Consider the distance function $r(x):=d(p,x)$. It is well-known that $r$ is smooth outside $\operatorname{cut}(p)\cup\{p\}$ where $\operatorname{cut}(p)$ is the cut locus of $p$. My question is:

> Is $r$ necessarily nonsmooth on every point of $\operatorname{cut}(p)$?

It is well-known that $x\in\operatorname{cut}(p)$ if and only if either (a) there are two distinct unit-speed minimizing geodesics $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,\ell]\to M$ joining $p$ and $x$, or (b) $x$ is a critical value of $\exp_p$. In Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry*, the author gave a remark on this: In case (a), $\nabla r$ could be either $\gamma_1'(\ell)$ or $\gamma_2'(\ell)$ and hence does not exist; in case (b), $\operatorname{Hess}r$ is undefined since it must tend to $-\infty$ along certain
fields.

I know that the part about (a) is intuitive, but is there any way to make the argument rigorous? O the other hand, I don't see why $\operatorname{Hess}r$ must blow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: Yes, they are non-smooth.

For a): Let $U$ be the set on which $r$ is differentiable. Since $r$ is 1-Lipschitz, we have $\Vert \nabla r \Vert \le 1$. Anyway, what I want to show is that for any shortest geodesic $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, we have $$(\nabla r)_{\gamma(t)} = \gamma'(t).$$
For this, let $v \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ be arbitrary and $\tilde{\gamma}$ the geodesic with $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = \gamma(t)$ and $\tilde{\gamma}'(0) = v$. Then we can compute $$\langle(\nabla r)_{\gamma(t)},v\rangle = (dr)_{\gamma(t)} \cdot v = \frac{d}{dt}_{\vert t=0} r(\tilde{\gamma}(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}_{\vert t=0} d(p,\tilde{\gamma}(t)) = \langle \gamma'(t), \tilde{\gamma}'(0)\rangle,$$
where the last equality follows from the first variation formula. By the uniqueness of the gradient we gain our claim.

Also, here's another way of computing $(\nabla r)_{\gamma(t)}$ without using the first variation formula:
$$\langle \nabla r, \gamma' \rangle = \frac{d}{dt} r(\gamma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} t = 1$$
but also by Cauchy Schwarz
$$\langle \nabla r, \gamma' \rangle \le 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$
and hence we have $\nabla r = \gamma'$.

Notice that we computed $\frac{d}{dt} r(\gamma(t))$ with the limit from below, assuming it was differentiable. So, if you are in case a) and assumed $r$ was differentiable in $x$, then you would get $\nabla r(x) = \gamma_1'(x)$ but also $\nabla r(x) = \gamma_2'(x)$, which is a contradiction.

For b): If $\gamma:[0,L] \to M^n$ is a geodesic and $x = \gamma(L)$ its first conjugated point to $p = \gamma(0)$, then the Weingarten map $A(t) = \nabla_\cdot N$ (where $N = \nabla r$ is a normed normal field along the distance spheres $S_t(p)$) has a pole in $t = L$. This is because $A(t) \cdot J(t) = J'(t)$ for $0<t<L$ and $J$ any Jacobi field along $\gamma$ with $J(0)=0$ and $J'(0) \neq 0$. But since the two points are conjugated, there exists such a $J$ with also $J(L)=0$ and $J'(L) \neq 0$ (otherwise $J\equiv 0$). Thus $$\lim\limits_{t \to L} A(t) \cdot J(t) = \lim\limits_{t \to L} J'(t) = J'(L) \neq 0,$$ but $$\lim\limits_{t \to L} J(t) = 0,$$ so $A(t)$ must blow up for $t \rightarrow L$.

Since the Hessian of $r$ is (tangentially to the distance spheres) given by the Weingarten map, the claim follows, since if $r$ were smooth at $x = \gamma(T)$ then $A(t)$ was continuous which is impossible since $\lim\limits_{t \to T} A(t)$ blows up. Thus, $r$ can't be contiuously differentiable at $x$.

Comment: The problem is that $d(p,\tilde{\gamma}(t))$ may not be realized by the curves in your variation, so you cannot apply the first variation formula. In other words, it may not be possible to construct a variation consisting all of shortest geodesics. Consider the case of spheres. Choose any shortest geodesic $\gamma$ connecting the north and south poles, then choose any vector $v$ at the north pole orthogonal to the chosen geodesic. As in your answer, we have $\tilde{\gamma}$. But the shortest geodesic from the south pole to $\tilde{\gamma}(t)$ changes drastically as $t$ goes away from $0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why I wrote "this helps you for (a)". You pointed out the problem. I assumed $U$ to be the set on which $r$ is differentiable. In that case, the curves $\tilde{\gamma}$ realize the distance. In other words: In case (a), the answer is yes: $r$ is nonsmooth in these points.

Comment: The "problem" was referring to your argument... The derivative of $d(p,\tilde{\gamma}(t))$ is not computable from the first variation formula, because you simply can't find a variation with all nearby curves shortest, as in the example I gave in the previous comment. So it does not constitute a proof for nonsmoothness.

Comment: In other words, near the cut locus, the shortest geodesic does not "depend smoothly" on the endpoint, so you can't use the first variation formula to compute the gradient of the distance function.

Comment: Okay, I finally see your point. Looking forward to seeing others participate.

Comment: I added some stuff.

Comment: I could see (a) now. Basically we only differentiate along our geodesic. ;) About (b): I'm not sure what your Weingarten map is referring to. If you mean something induced by the second fundamental form of geodesic spheres, then it's probably not that simple, because in (b) geodesic spheres aren't (immersed) submanifolds. Besides, take a look at this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159715/cut-locus-conjugate-points-and-smoothness-of-distance-function/159717?noredirect=1. If the answer there is true, it implies that we could have smoothness in (b).

Comment: I added some stuff. Also, I don't get the authors arguments on your linked question.

Comment: I see what blowing up was talking about. Thank you very much! So an even subtler question is this: In (b), although $\operatorname{Hess}r$ cannot exist, is it true that $\nabla r$ exists? And about the question which I previously linked: maybe the argument there only shows $\nabla r$ exists. BTW I don't understand that argument either.

Comment: Yea, I think that might be. Maybe $r$ is just differentiable, but not continuously differentiable. Or can't there be differentiable functions with second derivate blowing up?

Comment: For the case of a first conjugate point to a fixed point but with a unique minimal geodesic connecting these two points, the distance function may be differentiable at this conjugate point but not up to 2nd order differentiability. Please see post here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403600/riemannian-geometry-differentiability-of-distance-function-at-first-conjugate

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer another answer on why $\mathrm{Hess}r$ blows up. Actuarally the following arguement has already been contained on Petersen's book.

Suppose $\gamma:[0,l]\to M$ be a unique minimizing geodesic connecting $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(l)$ with $\gamma(l)$ being the first conjugate point to $p$. Suppose $J$ is a nontrivial Jacobi field along $\gamma$ such that $J(0)=0=J(l)$.

If $r$ is smooth at $\gamma(0)$, then as (a) implies
$$\nabla r=\gamma'(l),$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Hess}r(J,J)&=JJr-\nabla_JJr=J\langle\gamma'(l),J\rangle-\langle\gamma'(l),\nabla_JJ\rangle\\
&=\langle \nabla_J\gamma'(l),J\rangle=\langle \nabla_{\gamma'(l)}J,J\rangle\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\Big{|}_{t=l}\langle J,J\rangle.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

But also note that $|J(t)|^2\to 0$ as $t\to l$ which implies $\log|J|^2\to -\infty$ as $t\to l$. By elementary calculus there exists a sequence $\{t_k\}$ such that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{2\mathrm{Hess}r(J(t_k),J(t_k))}{|J(t_k)|^2}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{d}{dt}\Big{|}_{t=t_k}\log |J|^2= -\infty.$$

Define a smooth vector field along $\gamma(t)$ by $$X(t)=\frac{J(t)}{|J(t)|}.$$ The norm of $X(t)$ equals $1$.

In local coordinates around $\gamma(l)$, we can assume $X(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big{|}_{\gamma(t)}$. Since the norm of $X$ is bounded, we can subtract a subsequence $\{t_{k_l}\} $of $\{t_k\}$ such that $X^i(t_{k_l})$ converges to some number $X^i$. Now $X(t_{k_l})$ converges to some $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big{|}_{\gamma(l)}$

However, by what we previously argued $$\lim\limits_{l\to\infty}\mathrm{Hess}r(X(t_{k_l}),X(t_{k_l}))=-\infty,$$ thus $\mathrm{Hess}r(X,X)$ is not well defined.

Comment: a comment to your answer: (a) $Hess(r) (J,J) = (1/2) \partial_r \langle J, J \rangle$